# How to make bottom curve less then half in html

Tags: html, css

I want to make css for the bottom curve it is kind of less then half curve. but i am not be able to do that. i can only make it half curve.

Here i have tried but not work for

```css
.bottom {
  height: 300px;
  width: 600px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 600px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 600px;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottom"></div>
```

Here is what i want to do.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```css
.bottom {
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto -150px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
}
.outerDiv {
  overflow: hidden;
}
body {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerDiv">
    <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.bottom {
  height: 300px;
  width: 600px;
  border-radius: 100%/0 0 140px 140px;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottom"></div>
```

Comment: in the corner it is getting more curve  https://i.imgur.com/TKhijWZ.png

Comment: So do you want to reduce it?

Comment: yes like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEJ8B.jpg

Comment: Let me edit....

Comment: Confused. You want to border top curve or border bottom curve?

Comment: ohh sorry for that. have a look the difference b/t this  want this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEJ8B.jpg) vs used your css (https://i.imgur.com/TKhijWZ.png)